# How to delete certain sentences between 2 words before forwarding the email?

Tags: regex, vb.net, email

I have successfully written a script that can change the subject and then forward to a new recipient.

My current script is as such

```
With FwdMsg
NewLine = "Dear users,Please note that we are affected by the incident below and will be corrected after systems recovers. Please email the team  for more information.Thank you."
FwdMsg.HTMLBody = NewLine & FwdMsg.HTMLBody 

FwdMsg.Recipients.Add "hidden@mail"
FwdMsg.Subject = "Incident affecting you" & Format$(Now, " dd-mm-yyyy hh.mmam/pm")
FwdMsg.send
```

However I now need to delete certain sentences in the email and replace them with `please call me.`.

This is my email body:

```
Impact:
ABCD EFG RSTUV
ASDFT
Corrective Action
```

I need to remove the `AABCD EFG RSTUV ASDFT` and replace with a sentence `please call me` such that the new email body is:

```
Impact:

please call me with this number

Corrective Action
```

How do I do that with regex?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
  Dim pattern As String
  pattern = "Impact:.*Correction"
  Msginput " " & pattern
  Dim Msginput As String
  Msginput = FwdMsg.HTMLBody
  MsgBox " " & Msginput
   Dim replacement As String
   replacement = "please call me"
   Dim rgx As New RegExp
  Dim result As String
  result = rgx.Replace(Msginput, replacement)
  FwdMsg.HTMLBody = result
```

Comment: Your Regular Expression should be: `(?<=Impact\:).*(?=Corrective Action)`

Comment: Need to also specify `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a find and replace with capture buffers that lets you control the output format.
Have to use the regex *MULTILINE* option as beginning of line is used as delimiters.

Find:

```
^(Impact:)\s*(?:(?!^(?:Imapct:|Corrective[^\S\n]+Action))[\s\S])*^(Corrective[^\S\n]+Action)
```

Replace:

```
$1\n\nplease call me with this number\n\n$2
```

Expanded Regex:

```
 ^ 
 ( Impact: )
 \s* 
 (?:
      (?!
           ^ 
           (?:
                Imapct:  
             |  Corrective [^\S\n]+ Action
           )
      )
      [\s\S] 
 )*
 ^ 
 ( Corrective [^\S\n]+ Action )
```